# Term for making someone feel bad for asking a question

Tags: word-request

I came up with the term "condescending." Example being "Why did you ask this follow-up question? I've already helped you far more than your colleagues" and "You are already supposed to be self-propelling. I'm going out of my way to instruct you on your work." when coming from a boss. But, that may not be the word.

Comment: To be clear, the second example of a boss's response might be described as "condescending," since it contains some arrogance. The first isn't necessarily "condescending," though it might be many other things—hostile, aggressive, demanding, stingy, nearsighted, and as mentioned below, belittling...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a specific word for "being made to feel bad for asking a question". You can describe what the boss did as [**condescending**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/condescending):

> showing that you think you are more important or more intelligent than other people

or say that your boss [**embarrassed**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/embarrass#embarrass__1) you:

> to make someone feel nervous, ashamed, or stupid in a social situation

or [**belittled**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/belittle) you:

> to say or think that someone or something is unimportant or not very good

but those are more general, and you'd have to describe the situation in more detail.

Comment: (also - I've never seen the term *self-propelling* being used towards people. The metaphor is clear, but it doesn't seem idiomatic to me - any specific examples of that usage?).

Comment: A near-synonym of "belittle" that might also work is "humiliate".